# Javascript runtime error:

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, runtime-error

I am calling the following JS to validate a UK postal code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function jsre(theField) {
        var chk_postalcode = "^[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*\d[A-Z0-9 ]*$|^[A-Z0-9 ]*\d[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*$";
        var txtpostalcode = document.getElementById("txtPostCode");

        if (!chk_postalcode.test(txtpostalcode.value)) {
            alert("Valid");
        } else {
            alert("Invalid");
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPostCode" runat="server" onchange="jsre(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

I get the runtime error as:

```
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'test'
```

I took the help from http://www.9lessons.info/2009/03/perfect-javascript-form-validation.html to frame my code.

Can anyone help me how can i make the code working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"^[A-Z0-9 ][A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]\d[A-Z0-9 ]$|^[A-Z0-9 ]\d[A-Z0-9 ][A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]$"` change it to `/^[A-Z0-9 ][A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]\d[A-Z0-9 ]$|^[A-Z0-9 ]\d[A-Z0-9 ][A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]$/`. Remove double quotes and put slash.

Answer (score 4):

`chk_postalcode` is still a `string` so it has no `test()` method.

turn it into a RegExp object:

```
var chk_postalcode = /^[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*\d[A-Z0-9 ]*$|^[A-Z0-9 ]*\d[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*$/;
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be:

```
//add slashes and remove quotes
var chk_postalcode = /^[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*\d[A-Z0-9 ]*$|^[A-Z0-9 ]*\d[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*$/;
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var chk_postalcode = /^[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*\d[A-Z0-9 ]*$|^[A-Z0-9 ]*\d[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*$/;
```